# Java - standard SSL certificate all-trusting code fails

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I think that by now, nearly every Java coder who's had experience with SSL certificate trusting errors has used or at least encountered this code:

```
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts;
    trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    return true;
        }
};

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

So far, I have used this code with success to ignor certificate mismatches when accessing an HTTPs site via its IP address (don't ask me why I do it, it's a completely different story). However, I tried to do the same thing for another HTTPs site, and found that this code fails with the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

So, the question is, what is wrong, and what can I do about it?

Comment: The complete lack of merit of this technique aside, it has nothing to do with HTTPS certificate mismatches. The correct approach to that is to install a custom HostnameVerifier.

Comment: @EJP: hmm, I thought that this code handled this, too:
`// Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    return true;
        }
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. It looks like the server is using MD2 in its certificate. So far, the only fix I know for this problem is locating the jre/lib/security/java.security file in your JDK path and changing jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2 to jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms= so that the MD2 algorithm isn't disabled. This looks really nasty, but, sadly, I couldn't find a way to enable MD2 programmatically.

Looking back, I now remember that I COULD access it, but only before I updated Java, which killed the java.security file edit.